# Jquery iterate body element count each table height

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

Without id's i would like with jquery iterate the content of body element and for each table, find out its height.

Giving this HTML:

```
<iframe id="A">
<html>
 <head></head>
 <body>
   <table></table>
   <table></table>
   <table></table>
   <table></table>
  </body>
</html>
</iframe>
```

Comment: As a regular jQuery user you can’t come up with `$("table").each(…)` yourself – what’s the problem …?

Comment: I'm sorry i forgot to say that this body element is inside an iframe.

Comment: You still forgot to say how that’s a problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This counts the number of TRs in a table.

```
$("table").each(function(index)
{
   console.log( "table " + index + ": " + getElements($(this)));
});

function getElements(element) {
    var originalTable = element.clone();
    var trs = $(originalTable).children('tbody').children('tr').length;
    return trs;
}
```

Is this the height you are looking for ?

Comment: I forgot this is inside an iframe so this doesn´t work, but it helps ;)

Comment: What if you change the selector to be: $("iframe#A table").each(...)

Comment: Another solution might be: $("table, #A").each(...)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `each()` method in jQuery

```
$('body').find('table').each(function(){
    console.log($(this).height());
})
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/pranavcbalan/bycpr/)

or

```
$('body table').each(function(){
    console.log($(this).height());
})
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/pranavcbalan/bycpr/1/)

Comment: I forgot this is inside an iframe so this doesn´t work, but it helps ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `table` as selector and then use [**.each()**](http://api.jquery.com/each/)

```
$("body table").each(function () {
    var tableBodyHeight = $(this).find(tbody).height()
});
```

OR

```
$("body table tbody").each(function () {
    var tableBodyHeight = $(this).height()
});
```

Comment: I forgot this is inside an iframe so this doesn´t work, but it helps ;)